# How to find value from multiples classes ahveing same name using python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

I am able to find value from the first class with span.
I'm trying to find value from inner classes but they have the same name.

here is the html code:

```
<a class="jss1qhutbl jss1jy44eu" href="/quote/nasdaq-cxdc" aria-label="View quote detail page of CXDC" style="width: 60px; text-align: left;">CXDC</a>
<span class="jss1qhutbl jss15180ci" style="width: 80px; text-align: right;">0.9300</span>

<a class="jss1qhutbl jss1jy44eu" href="/quote/nasdaq-arct" aria-label="View quote detail page of ARCT" style="width: 60px; text-align: left;">ARCT</a>
<span class="jss1qhutbl jss15180ci" style="width: 80px; text-align: right;">58.25</span>
```

i found name of CXDC and ARCT with:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a.jss1qhutbl.jss1jy44eu")
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a.jss1qhutbl.jss1jy44eu")[1]
```

With help i found the price for CXDC with:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(@class,'jss1qhutbl jss15180ci')]").text
```

But im not able to find the price for ARCT:

i tried this:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('(.//span[@class = "jss1qhutbl jss15180ci"])')[1].text
```

Comment: Is there any parent tag before `<a>` and `<span>`?

Answer (score 0):

Xpath you used is wrong. See if this works

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='jss1qhutbl jss15180ci'][1]").text
```

OR

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@aria-label,'ARCT')]//following::span").text
```

Comment: your solution get the second value from the same class of 'jss1qhutbl jss15180ci'. In fact you van check here the page where i'm trying to get value of the first, second and third stock.  please have a look here: https://www.webull.com/quote/rankgainer

Comment: Try changing the index from 2 to 1 which will fetch the value you are expecting. Updated my code.

Comment: Finally i went with a compplicated xpath like this: //*[@id='app']/section/section[2]/section/section[2]/div[2]/div[2]/span[2] but it's not elegant. it works.